# loading .mat files that contain structures

Tags: matlab

I have a my_VTFormat.mat file.

> load( 'my_VTFormat.mat')
>
> whos -file my_VTFormat.mat
>
> Name   Size    Bytes          CLass     Attributes
>
> out    1*1     162530720      struct
>
> out:
>       VT:     [16163840 * 121 double]
>
> ```
>    sizeX : 64
>
>    sizeY : 64
>
>    sizeZ : 40
>
>    sizeT : 121 
>
>    coorX : [163840*1 double]
>
>    coorY : [163840*1 double]
>
>    coorZ : [163840*1 double]
> ```

My question is how can I convert the .mat file into a matrix, where the column denotes the 
number of voxels; the row denotes the time series. That means each column is the time series
of a voxel. Then I can use the matrix get from the .mat file to do matrix calculation. Thank 
you guys! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the line `out: VT: [16163840 * 121 double]` it should be `163840 * 121` and not `16163840 * 121`. If my guess is correct, Your data is already in the form of a matrix. The code for your query would be the following (assuming `"out"` is your structure):

```
 data=out.VT;
 data=data'; % Now the matrix size would be 121 * 163840 and each column corresponds to... 
                % coorX(i),coorY(i),coorZ(i) voxel where i=1,2,3....163840.
```

If this does not work for you, please provide a sample file, so that we can provide you a solution.

Comment: the sample file? you mean the .mat file?

Comment: I still do not know how to attach a file from stackoverflow. I will try to send a .mat file to you.

Comment: send it to me at naveen.bhatraju@igib.in